# Align is not in correct format in python openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I tried a program in python to read data from excel when I retrieve data from Excel its not displaying in correct format.

Here is my sample excel data:

[image]

Here is my code

```
import os
os.getcwd()
import openpyxl
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('sample.xlsx')
type(wb)
wb.get_sheet_names()
sheet=wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
sheet.title
columns=3
rows=3
for r in range(1,rows+1):
    for c in range(1,columns+1):
            d=sheet.cell(row=r,column=c)
            print('%-8s'%d.value , end='')
            print('')
```

I want output like this

```
ID      Name    age     
1       Sam     12      
2       Arun    12
```

but I get like this:

```
ID      
Name    
age     
1       
Sam     
12      
2       
Arun    
12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the second `print('')`, which induces an unnecessary line break after displaying your data.

```
for r in range(1,rows+1):
    for c in range(1,columns+1):
        d=sheet.cell(row=r,column=c)
        print('%-8s'%d.value , end='')
        print('')                         <------There's the error
```

It will be executed after each data print instead of each line.

```
for r in range(1,rows+1):
    for c in range(1,columns+1):
        d=sheet.cell(row=r,column=c)
        print('%-8s'%d.value , end='')
    print('')
```

Just pull it back one indent level to call it after each line

Comment: Thanks Adalcar for solving my problem.